# That Unix game used for testing and benchmarking the system

Tags: unix, benchmarking

I remember having read about a game that was used in the first UNIX versions for testing if all libraries have been installed correctly and the overall benchmark of the system.

Does anyone know what it was called?

At Wikipedia I found "Space Travel" but it appears to be the game that lead to the development of UNIX.

Comment: `make world` is an epic game where you watch letters chase each other up the screen in a bid for global domination.

Comment: I might be too young, but I used to use Quake2 for that :-)

Comment: Ops, missed that last line, then I have no idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be referring to "core war" but that came along a bit after the "early" Unix era.  I don't remember any game/benchmark from the early BSD Unix versions I owned.  "make world" was a good benchmark - but only if you were a source code owner, and in the early days not everyone was as it was still proprietary AT&T property. AT&T did however allow university CS departments to get it under a very generous license arrangement.

Hotei

Answer (score 1):

Might it be ["Game of Life"](http://groups.csail.mit.edu/cag/raw/benchmark/suites/life/README.html)?  That seems to be associated with benchmarks.